# How to Vectorize a text comparison for loop in R? Fuzzy Match Longest Common Starting Substring

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, matching, fuzzy

The code below runs fine for small amounts of data, but when I want to compare perhaps 20,000 names with 20,000 other names, I'm running 400M for loops, which obviously is pretty slow. Is there a way to vectorize this for loop to help it run faster?

```
#The purpose of this is to find the longest common starting substring
library(stringr)
#Basic sample data
text1 <- as.vector(c("test","theatre"))
text2 <- as.vector(c("trick","text","zheater"))

#Adding right padding so when I test ==, I won't get error for different string lengths
pad.length <- max(nchar(text1),nchar(text2))

#adding right padding
text1a <- str_pad(text1, pad.length, "right", pad = "|")
text2a <- str_pad(text2, pad.length, "right", pad = "|")

#splitting into individual characters to determine longest common starting substring
text1b <- as.vector(strsplit(text1a,""))
text2b <- as.vector(strsplit(text2a,""))

#Creating a blank matrix for results
match.matrix <- matrix(, nrow = length(text1b), ncol = length(text2b))


for(i in 1:length(text1b)){
  for(k in 1:length(text2b)){

    match.matrix[i,k] = which.min( text1b[[i]] == text2b[[k]])-1

  }}
```

Comment: you could maybe use tries? do you need all the info in your matrix?

Comment: I don't need all the information, although I like having the distances for each possible combination.

When I use the stringdist package, it can handle 20k x 20k pretty fast and provides a complete matrix, so I know its using some sort of vectorization to do that. However the package does not have longest common starting substring as an option, which I need. 

Could you elaborate further on "tries"? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could make a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with one of your text vectors and look for prefix matches for each string of your second vector.

To do this in R, you could use the `triebeard` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/triebeard/vignettes/r_radix.html), here's a function:
It makes a trie with `text2`, then for each word in `text1`, takes the first letter, then the first 2 etc and looks for words in `text1` that shares a prefix. It breaks out of the loop when it does not find any.

```
library(triebeard)
using_trie <- function(text1,text2){
      #make the trie
      trie <- trie(keys=text2,values=1:length(text2))

      #create empty matrix
      match.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = length(text1), ncol = length(text2))

      for(i in 1:length(text1)){
        for(j in 1:nchar(text1[i])){
          #iteratively increase prefix length and find which words in text1 share  this prefix
          matches <- prefix_match(trie=trie,to_match=substr(text1[i],0,j))

          #if none are found, get out of the loop as looking at longer prefixes is useless
          if(is.na(matches[[1]][1])) break

          #fill the matrix with the current prefix length at the relevant indices
          match.matrix[i,matches[[1]]] <- j
        }
      }
      return(match.matrix)
    }
```

Here's a comparaison with two 1000 long vectors:

```
text1 <- sapply(1:1000,function(x) paste(sample(letters[1:5],10,replace=TRUE),collapse=""))
text2 <- sapply(1:1000,function(x) paste(sample(letters[1:5],10,replace=TRUE),collapse=""))

identical(using_loop(text1,text2),using_trie(text1,text2))
#[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(using_loop(text1,text2),using_trie(text1,text2))
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
 using_loop(text1, text2) 2420.944 2482.0098 2678.8023 2512.7551 2753.592 4475.7399   100
 using_trie(text1, text2)  257.346  273.3073  311.6431  299.8759  316.449  628.5882   100
```